# Reduce white space above chapter title, and reduce space between title and text, for unnumbered chapters

Tags: spacing, titlesec

How can I reduce the white space above the chapter heading?

How can I reduce the space between the heading and the text?

I want to be able to do this for selected chapters only, or after a given chapter (I want normal spacing from the Introduction chapter and outwards, but before that I want reduced spacing).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[b5paper, 11pt, twoside, openright]{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\begin{document}
\chapter*{Abstract}
This chapter should have less spacing
\chapter*{Preface}
This chapter should have less spacing
\tableofcontents %Less spacing
\listoffigures %Less spacing
\listoftables %Less spacing
\chapter*{Glossary}
Less spacing
\chapter{Introduction}
From this chapter, I want normal spacing
\end{document}
```

Comment: For single cases you will need to add `\vspace{-3cm}` or similar. For anything else, we will need an MWE. Reducing the spacing around the title for just certain chapters should be considered very bad typography. IMHO.

Comment: `\vspace{-3cm}` placed after the `\chapter{title}` works on the text, but how do I move the chapter heading?

Comment: the mechanism for positioning a chapter heading is different depending on what document class is being used.  so more information is necessary before a reliable answer can be provided.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Please see updated question :)

Comment: @Bernard: In another question, Bernard told that titlesec has the possibility for different spacing for numbered and unnumbered chapters. This is precisely what I am looking for! But how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this answer directly modifies the command from `report.cls` that formats
the headings of unnumbered chapters.

```
\documentclass[b5paper, 11pt, twoside, openright]{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makeschapterhead}[1]{%
%  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  \vspace*{20\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
%    \vskip 40\p@
    \vskip 20\p@
  }}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter*{Abstract}
This chapter should have less spacing
\chapter*{Preface}
This chapter should have less spacing
\tableofcontents %Less spacing
\listoffigures %Less spacing
\listoftables %Less spacing
\chapter*{Glossary}
Less spacing
\chapter{Introduction}
From this chapter, I want normal spacing
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have no doubt that your answer is better than mine. But what is the difference? Is there a difference?

Comment: i wouldn't necessarily say that one or the other answer is better.  some tex users feel more comfortable making all changes using packages, and some, by addressing the underlying code directly.  i am one of the latter; i have been burned by unexpected side effects encountered when adding a package that i'm not thoroughly familiar with.  `titlesec` has a good reputation, and here does what you ask of it.  my answer just provides another option for a very limited situation.

Answer (score 6):

`titlesec` supports different spacing for numbered and unnumbered chapters:

```
\documentclass[b5paper, 11pt]{report}

%%% Add this %%%
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename~\thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{40pt}
\titlespacing*{name=\chapter,numberless}{0pt}{-30pt}{10pt}
%%%   End   %%%


\begin{document}
\chapter*{Abstract}
This chapter should have less spacing
\chapter*{Preface}
This chapter should have less spacing
\tableofcontents %Less spacing
\listoffigures %Less spacing
\listoftables %Less spacing
\chapter*{Glossary}
Less spacing
\chapter{Introduction}
From this chapter, I want normal spacing
\end{document}
```