# How to move the Header/ Title closer to the fancyhdr ruler line (remove the space)

Tags: table-of-contents, fancyhdr

how can I remove the big space between the Header (e.g. List of Tables) and the fancyhdr? Do I need to set this in the \pagestyle definition?

Merci in advance A

```
\documentclass[openany,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{WHAT I WANT TO SEE}}


\begin{document}


\listoffigures % Prints the list of figures

\newpage
\listoftables % Prints the list of tables

\chapter{Prämissen des Modells}

Header is correct on this page.

\newpage

\section{Grundannahmen zum Modell diskrete Betriebsstunden}

And wrong on this one.
\end{document}
```

Comment: if you highlight all of the code and use the `{}` button (or ctrl-k shortcut) it will be formatted as code

Comment: Aeorius, did you have a look at  [`fancyhdr`](http://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf) package documentation ?

Comment: Also, not related to your question but why do you sign your questions with *merci in advance* ?

Comment: merci David, I didnt know how to do that...

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Space before chapters and contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39988/5764); [Reduce white space above chapter title, and reduce space between title and text, for unnumbered chapters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/249346/5764)

Comment: I did BambOo, although I couldnt figure out, which attribut is resposible for this issue, I have tried several from voffset, headheight etc, but it didnt work...its my 2nd week with latex, sorry, i try to learn as fast as I can, but it takes some time fo figure out, what belongs where to get the desired effekt...;-(

Comment: You can use `titlesec` to customise the formatting/spacing of `\chapter`.

Comment: Merci @Werner; that means I need to add the following code part?   \usepackage{titlesec}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makeschapterhead}[1]{%
%  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  \vspace*{20\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
%    \vskip 40\p@
    \vskip 20\p@
  }}
\makeatother

Comment: BTW - is there a way to Format Code in the comments as well, I can’t see the {} signs...

Comment: Aerioeus, see [TeX.SX starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). It is not an issue to learn, and learning latex for sure takes time, but when asking a question, it is very important to show people what you have tried so far (code snippets, web pages where you got information from ...). This way help will come faster !