# How to change a page layout in a Overleaf template?

Tags: page-numbering, layout

I am using a template from Overleaf [enter link description here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/university-of-rochester-masters-slash-phd-thesis-template/bwkpcxzdysky)

However, I have no idea where to change the page layout.
I want to write more in my `Abstract` page, while other page maintained the same as the template.

If I used this:

```
\usepackage[top=2cm,left=1.2cm,right=1.2cm, bottom=1cm]{geometry}
```

It will change all the pages. I just want `Abstract` page.

In the photo below, I want to word `Abstract` move to top a little, so that I can write more.
However, others title remain the same as template, Am I able to do that?

For example:

```
\include{structure/abstract}  %-> page size larger

\include{structure/acknowledgements}  %--> page remain in original size
```

[image]

```
  \documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}  % Remove draft option to show figures (for final draft), otherwise keep for faster production

\usepackage{uorthesis}  % Loads the LaTeX style package
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, dashed=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}


\usepackage{titlesec}
% \titleformat{\chapter}[block]
%   {\normalfont\sffamily\LARGE\bfseries\filcenter}
%   {\filcenter\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter\filcenter\\}{20pt}{\huge}
  
  
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]   {\normalfont\sffamily\LARGE\bfseries\filcenter}   {\filcenter\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter\filcenter\\}{20pt}{\huge}[{\titlerule[1pt]}]
  
  
  
 
% Put custom packages to be loaded here
% \usepackage{linguex}  % For linguistic examples
% \usepackage{tikz}     % For drawing

\begin{document}

% Title page


% All subsequent pages must be numbered, title page is considered page i,
% front matter is numbered in lowercase Roman numerals
\pagestyle{fancy}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{2}
\doublespacing

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% DISSERTATION CONTENT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Regular numbering starts now, first page of first chapter is page 1
\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{0}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

% Body


\include{structure/abstract}

\include{structure/acknowledgements}



% References
\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\markboth{\MakeUppercase{Bibliography}}{}
\singlespacing
\printbibliography


\end{document}
```

uorthesis.sty file:

```
% This defines everything necessary for a thesis
% Master's/PhD at UoR (or anywhere else).
%
% Do what you will with this package
% 
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{uorthesis}
  [2018/01/18 v0.01 LaTeX package for UOR thesis]

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nosep} % Removes too much vertical spacing in lists
\usepackage{booktabs}           % makes tables look good
\usepackage{fancyhdr}           % For page number in the upper right (required) and other running headers(optional)
\usepackage{setspace}           % For double-spacing (required)
\usepackage{titlesec}           % For keeping chapter/chapter titles single-spaced
\usepackage{etoolbox}           % For the flag determining if front matter goes into the TOC
\usepackage{float}              % Helps float images to the top
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
% Define custom colors
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0, 0, 0.5}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=darkblue]{hyperref}           % Adds hyperlinks in the pdf
\usepackage{csquotes}           % Makes quotes look good
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont={bf,sf}, textfont={sf}, justification=centering]{caption}

%% Font setup
\usepackage{mathptmx}
% \usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{helvet}

% Header height (to avoid fancyhdr error)
\setlength{\headheight}{13.6pt}

% Header formatting for regular pages
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\it\small\leftmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\small\thepage}

% Header formatting for chapter title pages
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[R]{\small\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

% Formatting of chapter and chapter titles: keep them single-spaced in the midst of double-spaced text

\usepackage{sectsty}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\sffamily\bfseries}{\thechapter{. }}{0pt}{\Huge}
\allsectionsfont{\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft} % subfigure option only if using subfigure package
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\Huge \bfseries \sffamily} % ToC title
\addto\captionsenglish{
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\textsf{List of Figures}}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{\textsf{List of Tables}}
}

% Flag for whether to add front matter to TOC
\newtoggle{fulltoc}
\toggletrue{fulltoc}  % Change to \togglefalse{fulltoc} to remove front matter
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}

\endinput
%%
%% End of file `uorthesis.sty'.
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable. Since all the files you include using the `\include` command are not available (and most likely their exact contents are nevertheless not relevant to the question itself), please remove them and replace them with some suitable dummy contents.

Comment: @leandriis thanks for your suggestion. I had edited it. and only `\include{structure/abstract} \include{structure/acknowledgements}`.

Comment: From the image you show I guess that the  "abstract" file starts with something like `\chapter*{abstract}`. Is that correct? You mention you want the chapter title of the abstract to change position while keeping all other chapter titles where they currently are. Do you have other unnumbered chapters  (`\chapter*`) in your document? Should they change position as well? Please clarify.

Comment: In case you want to affect all unnumbered chapter titles, take a look at (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/249370/134144)

Comment: @leandriis Thanks. It worked, it took an hour to check and it works well. In answering to your question, yes, I have other `\chapter` that I do not want to change the size.