# How to have a underline in a Chapter page?

Tags: underline

I want to have a black color underline as shown below:

[image]

My MWE seemed a bit long:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}  % Remove draft option to show figures (for final draft), otherwise keep for faster production

\usepackage{uorthesis}  % Loads the LaTeX style package
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, dashed=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\usepackage{uorbib}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
  {\normalfont\sffamily\LARGE\bfseries\filcenter}
  {\filcenter\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter\filcenter\\}{20pt}{\huge}
  
 
% Put custom packages to be loaded here
% \usepackage{linguex}  % For linguistic examples
% \usepackage{tikz}     % For drawing

\begin{document}

% Title page
\include{structure/title}

% All subsequent pages must be numbered, title page is considered page i,
% front matter is numbered in lowercase Roman numerals
\pagestyle{fancy}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{2}
\doublespacing

% Dedication (optional)
\include{structure/dedication}

% Acknowledgments
\include{structure/acknowledgements}

% Abstract
\include{structure/abstract}

% Table of Contents, List of Tables, List of Figures
\tableofcontents

%List of Tables & Figures
\include{structure/tablesfigures}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% DISSERTATION CONTENT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Regular numbering starts now, first page of first chapter is page 1
\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{0}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

% Body


\include{chapters/01-introduction}

\include{chapters/02-background}

\include{chapters/03-chapter}

\include{chapters/04-chapter}

% References
\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\markboth{\MakeUppercase{Bibliography}}{}
\singlespacing
\printbibliography

\appendix
\include{chapters/99-appendix}

\end{document}
```

However, I think the main code is:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
  {\normalfont\sffamily\LARGE\bfseries\filcenter}
  {\filcenter\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter\filcenter\\}{20pt}{\huge}
```

Comment: Do you want to underline the last line of the title or do you want to draw a line between the title and the following text?

Comment: @henryflower I want to draw `a line between the title and following text`. Sorry that my question is not clear enough

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others can compile. Where did you get the files `uorthesis.sty` and `uorbib.sty` from? Also, please replace all `\include{...}` commands with some dummy text.

Comment: Probably `\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
  {\normalfont\sffamily\LARGE\bfseries\filcenter}
  {\filcenter\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter\filcenter\\}{20pt}{\huge}[{\titlerule[1pt]}]` results in the desired output? (See also: [Add a rule after chapter title using titlesec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69330/134144))

Comment: @leandriis. Thanks. It worked. Brillant. Can you have a look at similar template https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/560388/how-to-change-a-page-layout-in-a-overleaf-template

Comment: Since the suggestion to use `titlerule` from my previous comment as well as from the answer of the question I linked to, seems to have solved your question, I have voted to close your question as a duplicate to the other one. [Add a rule after chapter title using titlesec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69330/add-a-rule-after-chapter-title-using-titlesec)

Comment: @leandriis, yes, it answer and your suggestion above worked well too. Between, another similar template, where I want to adjust the page size https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/560388/how-to-change-a-page-layout-in-a-overleaf-template